# How are charges formed in clouds during lightning?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, lightning

How are charges formed in clouds that are responsible for lightning?

Comment: From Wikipedia entry on lightning: "It is well understood that during a thunderstorm there is charge separation and aggregation in certain regions of the cloud; however the exact processes by which this occurs are not fully understood"

Answer (score 2):

The conditions needed to produce lightning have been known for some time. However, exactly how lightning forms has never been verified so there is room for debate. Leading theories focus around separation of electric charge and generation of an electric field within a thunderstorm. Recent studies also indicate that ice, hail, and semi-frozen water drops known as graupel are essential to lightning development. Storms that fail to produce large quantities of ice usually fail to produce lightning.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud droplets have the unique ability to geometrically sequence, that is, increase in size by coalescence while contemporaneously decreasing their surface area. This inverse relationship allows whatever charges they have collected by solar radiation to increase the surface charge density on the droplets. The few ions present in the neighboring air will be accelerated so strongly more ions are created by cumulative collision allowing the electricity to escape. This sequence is repeated throughout the entire cloud producing a vast electric field strong enough to break down the dielectric (air).